# Query in a way to show books that belong to different authors

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

```
select subject, authors, authorID
from library with (nolock)
inner join authors with (nolock) bookid = bookauthorID
where subject = 'Russian History'
```

So I want to write a query that will show that all the authors that have written books on Russian History, and I want to show column categoryID as "multiple" if there are more than 2 different authors that written on the subject, and vice versa as "single".

Example:

```
CategoryID  Author
2009940     Steve Cohen
```

From the above ID, it would return as single, since there's only one distinctive author on this ID.

Would be the best to achieve this using `count(min)`?

Comment: is authors actual column name in your select statement?

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). That is not "BEST" anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't provide a desired output nor do I believe you have shared the appropriate objects for your tables/columns but you can alter this for your needs.

You just need to reference a `COUNT(DISTINCT columnName)` to see if its greater than 1 or not.

```
select 
    subject
    , CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT authors) = 1 THEN 'single' 
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT authors) > 1 THEN 'multiple' 
        END AS Authors
from library 
inner join authors bookid = bookauthorID
where subject = 'Russian History'
GROUP BY subject
```